redirect only strings without backslashes and dots in URL with htaccess
I want to use htaccess to redirect any requested path of example.com/myvar ( where
myvar is a string of [a-zA-Z0-9_] ) to router.php . which lets any URL with a backslash such as exemple.com/admin/ to run as well as any URL that has a dot such as exemple.com/signout.php to run without redirecting.
so far this is what I came up with but it is functioning a bit weirdly :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?!\.|\/)(?:(\//)(.*)|)$
RewriteRule (.*) router.php [QSA,L]


try the following set of rules:

Ensure the request is not for a file (like .php or .css) or a directory (with a trailing slash):
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


Match any request where the first path segment is alphanumeric or underscore, and there's no dot or trailing slash after it:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$


Redirect such requests to router.php:
RewriteRule ^ /router.php [QSA,L]



Expected behavior:

Requests like example.com/admin/ (which has a trailing slash) or example.com/signout.php (which contains a dot) will pass through without redirection.
Requests like example.com/myvar (where myvar is a string with alphanumeric characters or underscores) will be redirected to router.php.

Hope it helps ;]

Fantastic. Seems to be working nicely in local mamp (still didn't test it on my host). one weird behavior though (and not an issue) : when I go to 'example.com/admin' without any dash, it still takes me to the dashboard instead of taking my to router.php (same thing with any folder I make that has an index)
